# How to eliminate rows in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, keyerror

this is a beginner question, but I could not find the answer to this particular problem anywhere.

I am trying to graph two values using matplotlib, I have have a CSV table, and I am using Pandas to manipulate it. When trying to graph I get "Key error, not in index".

This is because some the values in my table are missing. So I say

```
df = df.dropna()
```

I have two values I am trying to graph v_d and v_a. The problem is that some of the "N/A" or missing values may be missing from the v_a row but not from v_d row.

I do not know how to completely delete a row if any of the values are missing, and then rearrange my df so that there are no holes or gaps. Basically to remove all rows that have any missing data in v_d or v_a, and then shuffle then slide the remaining rows to take their spots.

I believe this would prevent me from getting the key error.

EDIT: for more information in response to my question

Here is specifically what I am trying to plot

```
df.plot.scatter(x = df.v_d[df.V > 0.1], xlim=[-500,500] , y = df.v_a[df.V > 0.1] , ylim=[-500,500])
```

where V is another quantity I defined

When I try to plot this I get a key error not in index - I was assuming it was because some of my values of v_d and v_a are n/a

*What I really wanted to know, and could not find in the documentation for drop.na() is how to drop a row completely if any value in the row is null.*

Comment: That does drop all null values? it satisfy your requirements.

Comment: I suspect there's something else going on here. Can you provide some more code, to make this issue reproducible?

Comment: What is the actual code you used for `df=df.dropna()`? Did you read through the docs? `DataFrame.dropna(axis=0, how='any', thresh=None, subset=None, inplace=False)` It sounds like you're describing `axis=0`, `how = 'any`, and `subset=['v_a', 'v_d']`. What exactly didn't work?

Comment: `I have two values I am trying to graph v_d and v_a` What does this mean? What are `values`? You have two pandas DataFrame? two pandas Series?

Comment: Also, `matplotlib` has no issue plotting `Series` against each other where one of the values is `null`. The lines will be interrupted because of the `null` breaks, but it will still mark points for any valid pair where both are not-null

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I needed to do

```
df = df[np.isfinite(df['v_d'])]
```

etc ...

posting this solution in case anyone else has this problem.